# Timestamp problems

Tags: java, timestamp

For an app I'm making I have to convert a Timestamp into time. I have looked around on the internet quite a bit and have tried several ways to do this within Java, but it keeps giving me the wrong time/date. Could it be that the timestamp I'm using has a different format or am I just coding it wrong.

These are 2 examples of timestamp I have to use:

1379701800 which is: friday, 20 september 2013 at 20:30 (GMT +1)

1379709000 which is exactly 2 hours later (22:30)

How would I convert those timestamps into a time within Java?

Edit. Fixed. If you are having trouble with timestamps make sure that you try multiplying the number with 1000.

Comment: You want to exactly add 2 hours to the first Timestamp in android?

Comment: Off the cuff, those look like milliseconds-since-the-Unix-epoch values, in which case use `setTimeInMillis()` on `Calendar`. However, it would help if you indicated how those numbers are being generated.

Comment: I'm not trying to add 2 hours to the time stamp. Those are 2 different time stamps that are 2 hours apart. I didn't get the time from the stamp, but from a website using the same stamps. I can't tell how the numbers are generated since I don't make them, but load them from a website.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this to solve it:

```
Timestamp stamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date date = new Date(stamp.getTime());
System.out.println(date);
```

Since you are not showing any code, we can't tell you what is wrong with it.

Comment: When I use that code with my custom time stamp, the date that is printed out is: Sat Jan 17 00:15:44 CET 1970 which is completely wrong. It should be 2013 to start with. The currentTimeMilis time does work though.